# How to restrict direct file/url download and access?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, file

I have a website eg. subdomain.example.com

The website works as follows

Scenario 1
 
When visitor logs into website the get a signup form
     
if they fill the form then a php scripts run 
     
a. http://subdomain.example.com/subscribe.php

if they completed signup successfully then site returns
   
b.   http://subdomain.example.com/success.html
   
if failed then site returns 

c.   http://subdomain.example.com/error.html

2. Scenario 2

   There is another form to download a pdf after successful form fillup it executes a email to that user and send download link.

Solution needed :

1. I want no one can type link a,b,c in the browser and can be able to visit the site , site links can be visible if it is referred by the steps (If any one completes the procedure )
2. How to stop passing data by writiing values with a link in url. eg.

http://subdomain.example.com/subscribe.php?post[parameters]

3. How to set the accesskey system to make the download valid for single time and file cannot be accessible for direct link visit without api key.

Answer (score 0):

They are a lot of ways to do this.... One way I do this is by generating an MD5 key  and getting Radom strings from the generated key, then I use the super GET global variable to search for it ... Then use password_verify() function to verify the hash is correct ... Next I would do is that when uploading the file I create a column for date and insert the current date using the now() function, so when I verify the md5() code i also immediately verify how long it has taken since link generated.

I am sorry I am on a mobile phone... Would have loved to help you on this one, had done I for a client before..

Comment: Thanks let me try